# ios_distribution.cer was revoked, can I submit to AppStore?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, code-signing, application-loader

I think the answer is no, but I need to make sure.

- The ios_distribution.cer file shows as revoked
- The provisioning file shows as invalid (*is that because the cer was revoked?*)

I do not generate the certificates myself, I just build the apps. My client has someone else build the certs, and also someone else must have revoked it.

I'm submitting to the AppStore today and Application Loader gives the following error:

> Application failed codesign verification.   The signature was invalid,
>   contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone
>   Distribution Certificate.

Is the error caused because the certificate is revoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No you cannot submit it!**

I'm answering my own question because I've just rebuilt the app with a new certificate.

- Yes, the provisioning file shows as invalid because the certificate was revoked.
- Yes, the error was because the certificate was revoked.

*Obviously you cannot submit it - That would defeat the point of revoking a certificate in the first place.*